# limit for minus infinity for $\ln(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, infinity

For calculating a vertical asymptote, I need to evaluate for $x$ going to $-1$:

$f(x) = \ln(x/x+1)$

$\lim_{x\to -1} \ln(x/(x+1)) $

After applying the chain rule for limits, it seems I need to evaluate $\ln(x)$ for $x$ going to minus infinity. That's outside the definition of this function. But, apparently the answer is positive infinity. How to derive limits for $x$ reaching outside the definitions of functions? Or am I applying the chain rule incorrectly?

thx in advance

babi

Comment: Doesn't make sense, since $x/(x+1) < 0$ with $-1 < x < 0$.

Comment: The limit from the right-hand side does not exist since $\frac{x}{x+1}<0$ for $-1<x<0$.  The limit from the left-hand side is $\infty$.

Comment: Ah, so my error was to fill in -1 for x in my head, while I should have "filled in" like e.g. 1.000001, to calculate the LEFT limit, and so the minus in the nominator and denominator cancel, and I have to calculate ln of positive infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x)=\ln\frac{x}{x+1}$ is defined where
$$
\frac{x}{x+1}>0
$$
that is, in the set $(-\infty,-1)\cup(0,\infty)$.

Since
$$
\lim_{x\to-1^-}\frac{x}{x+1}=\infty
$$
you have
$$
\lim_{x\to-1^-}f(x)=\infty
$$
because $\lim_{t\to\infty}\ln t=\infty$.

Similarly,
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\infty
$$

So you have two vertical asymptotes at $-1$ (from the left) and at $0$ (from the right).

[image]